# Amazon EBS High Usage Costs

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a SpringBoot application running on an Amazon EC2 instance that uses Amazon EBS disk storage. The application receives JSON data as HTTP and stores it into an Amazon RDS (MySQL) database.

In total, the application received data from 600 processes. Each process sent JSON for approximately 0.1mb, so ~60mb of data were sent in total.

However, my EBS charges were ~$36 of `USE2-EBS:VolumeUsage.gp2` which is priced at $0.1/GB. If I look at my billing summary, I find:

> $0.10 per GB-month of General Purpose SSD (gp2) provisioned storage - US East (Ohio)1,048.230 GB-Mo$104.82

This is cumulative throughout the month where I ran my processes several other times, but I am really struggling to understand how I am generating this much data given that the size of the JSON I sent over HTTP is far inferior.

Any advice on how I could get further insight into this?

Comment: You don't "run" on EBS; it's a (logical) disk drive. You pay for it based on the amount of storage that you allocate. If you allocate a 1 TB drive you will pay $100/month. The important thing is that _you_ allocated the space, either for the EC2 instance where you're actually running your program, or (more likely) for the RDS database where you're storing your data. You need to look there to find answers.

Comment: Thanks! I have one t2.micro and one t2.medium, plus one db.t2.medium database. t2.micro shoul be in free tier, for the rest should I consider the 13gb (5 from db2.medium and 8 from t2.large) and multiply by the number of hours?

Comment: @MrD also, EBS (Elastic Block Store) is not "memory usage" as mentioned in the question title.  Look at the EBS volumes in the EC2 console.  Note particularly, any volumes that are not attached to instances, and/or any volumes that are larger than expected.  You do not need to multiply by hours.  The price is $0.10 per GB for one month's worth of hours (approx $0.10/(30 * 24) per hour), so the hours cancel out.